# Public Key Cryptography in Solidity

Tags: solidity, cryptography

I'm trying to implement a contract that stores 2 public keys from 2 separate entities. Data delivery between two entities will be securely sent by using each other's public key. However, there is a situation that would require for both entities to encrypt the data with their respective private key, and for the contract to decrypt the ciphertext with the corresponding public key.

Is there a built-in method in solidity for asymmetric decryption?

Comment: so ... you will be uploading the secret key (to decrypt) to a public blockchain for everybody's eyes?

Comment: @Nulik Only the public key of both entities are ever stored on the contract. On this specific situation, Entity A and Entity B will use their private key to encrypt the data and sends it to the contract which will then decrypt the ciphertext with their public keys (similar to digital signatures).

Comment: you might be looking for [ecrecover](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions). This shows who signed the hash.